# Jenkins multiple builds from the same project in different slave nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Can I queue multiple builds from the same project in different slaves nodes and only one build per node? is there any plugin to do it?

Comment: Why wouldn't you bind the jobs to the needed servers?

Comment: If you bind the job to a particular node label that is shared by all of your slave nodes, then those jobs will only be built on those slave nodes. Furthermore, if you make each of your slave nodes only have 1 process, then you would achieve what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [matrix-project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin)

```
The Configuration Matrix allows you to specify what 
steps to duplicate, and create a multiple-axis graph 
of the type of builds to create.
```

Which also supports a [NodeLabel](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) plugin.

```
This plugin adds two new parameter types to job 
configuration - node and label, this allows to 
dynamically select the node where a job/project 
should be executed.
```

This combination will allow you to bind one configuration to selected (or all) nodes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you, specially to KeepCalmAndCarryOn,he give me a good hits to solve the problem.
Finally I have installed [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) and I have set the following options on the job config:
[image: Plugins Config]

Comment: Are you sure this solves it as you want? When I configure like this, then jenkins simply runs the exact same job on multiple nodes.